# how to inject confirmation text (HTML) back into webpage, (below the submission form) from a php script?

Tags: php

I have a form in my webpage that sends data submitted by the user to an email address. i.e. a contact form. I know how to open a new page to inform the user that the data has been fired off to the email address. However I do not want to open a new page, I just want to inject a simple `Email Sent!` text below the actual form for the user; instead of redirecting to a new page.

I have absolutely no idea how to achieve this in PHP. I have all the basics of the process script set up here;

```
<?php

/*--/ subject & email variables /--*/

$emailSubject = 'Email Title';
$webMaster = 'php.test@outlook.com';

/*--/ gathering data variables /--*/

$firstField = $_POST['first_Name'];
$lastField = $_POST['last_Name'];
$emailField = $_POST['email'];
$telField = $_POST['phone'];
$selectField = $_POST['select'];
$enquiryField = $_POST['enquiry'];

$body = <<<EOD
<br><hr><br>
First Name: $first_Name <br>
Last Name: $last_Name <br>
Email: $email <br>
Tel: $phone <br>
I heard about you from; $select <br>
Enquiry: $enquiry <br> 
EOD;

$headers = "From: $email\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n";
$success = mail($webMaster,$emailSubject, $body, $headers);
?>
```

If anyone can help I would be thankful.

Comment: PHP is serverside. What you want is not possible with php alone. Looks into javascript and xhr.

Comment: I see, is there no way to check that the php did fire, from the page that it was fired from then?

Comment: No, PHP code is ran *on the server side*. You should create an AJAX request using Javascript. Have a google of that, and there are a thousand decent tutorials for you.

Comment: Very well thank you! :P